# How to avoid info message that spring is logging on every web request

Tags: spring

I am using Spring 3.1.2 along with javax.inject.jar on the class-path and I get the following message printed to my log files. I get these six lines of output for every web request to the application.

```
00:53:11,291 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
00:53:11,301 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
00:53:11,309 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
00:53:11,417 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
00:53:11,431 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
00:53:11,455 INFO  [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
```

Question:

- Why is the above message being printed on every request?
- How to stop it from being printed on every request?

**UPDATE: Here is how spring boots up:**

```
<!-- Listeners that startup spring -->
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>


    <!-- main dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using JRebel and I am not sure if that starts extra contexts as part of its hacking the JVM and libraries to support live reload.

**Any debug flags or categories I can configure to figure out where the problem is occurring?**

Comment: You should only see that when an application context is being created.  Generally it's not a good idea to do that on every web request, so I suspect you might need to look at adopting a more conventional approach to context creation (e.g. once per servlet instance).  All the sample apps would do it right.

Comment: I am not creating a context on every request, I am using a servlet context listener to start spring on web app startup.

Comment: Well it looks like somehow a context is being created.  How is your servlet defined?  Is it a Spring DispatcherServlet?  You are going to have to provide some more detail.

Comment: Personally I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252743/change-spring-framework-log-level-in-simple-example-project) works like a magic.